# Is No Free Lunch Theorem generalizable to Quantum Computation?

Tags: optimization

The "[No Free Lunch Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem)" says: that when averaged across all possible problems, any two strategies have equivalent performance. However it uses Bayesian reasoning to arrive at this conclusion.

However, Bayesian reasoning employs [conditional probability](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/510364/150174) which does not hold in it's standard form in QM. Then the question becomes if I have 2 search algorithms in QM do they have
equivalent performance across all possible problems? Or in other words is No Free Lunch Theorem generalizable to Quantum Computation?